# Xero API signature invalid using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, xero-api

I am accessing API using Google Apps Script. I am looking for a https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/reports#TrialBalance

I have tried with the API code as but I get signature invaid as reposnse result [19-09-03 19:45:46:402 IST] oauth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_problem_advice=Failed%20to%20validate%20signature

```
function doGet(e) {
    getTrialBalances();
}

function getTrialBalances() {
    var oauth_nonce = createGuid();
    var oauth_timestamp = (new Date().valueOf() / 1000).toFixed(0);
    var CONSUMER_KEY = 'B7D5YA8D1HWHUZIGXL1AZS44N'
    var PEM_KEY = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' +
        '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' +
        '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

    var payload = '';

    var URL = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/TrialBalance';
    var signatureBase = "GET" + "&" +
        encodeURIComponent(URL) + "&" +
        encodeURIComponent('date=2019-02-01') + "&" +
        encodeURIComponent("oauth_consumer_key=" + CONSUMER_KEY +
            "&oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=" +
            oauth_timestamp + "&oauth_token=" + CONSUMER_KEY + "&oauth_version=1.0");
    var rsa = new RSAKey();
    rsa.readPrivateKeyFromPEMString(PEM_KEY);
    var hashAlg = "sha1";
    var hSig = rsa.signString(signatureBase, hashAlg);

    var oauth_signature = encodeURIComponent(hextob64(hSig));

    var authHeader = "OAuth oauth_token=\"" + CONSUMER_KEY + "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + oauth_nonce +
        "\",oauth_consumer_key=\"" + CONSUMER_KEY + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"RSA-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"" +
        oauth_timestamp + "\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"" + oauth_signature + "\"";
    var headers = {
        "Authorization": authHeader,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    };
    var options = {
        "headers": headers,
        'method': 'GET',
        'payload': payload,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    };

    var requestURL = URL + '?date=2019-02-01';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestURL, options);
    var responseXml = response.getContentText();
    Logger.log(responseXml);
}

function createGuid() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
            v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16)
    });
}
```

For RSA signing I have used https://github.com/csi-lk/google-app-script-xero-api/blob/master/jsrsasign.gs

**UPDATE 2:**

I code this, but still not able to get the result

```
var signatureBase = encodeURIComponent("GET" + "&" + URL + "&" + 'date=2019-02-01' + "&" + "oauth_consumer_key=" + CONSUMER_KEY +
            "&oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=" +
            oauth_timestamp + "&oauth_token=" + CONSUMER_KEY + "&oauth_version=1.0");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Before reading the rest of my answer can you please urgently reset your applications Consumer Key/Secret, as well as create and upload a new public certificate to the developer portal as you've provided both in your question.**

---

At least one issue you're running into that I can spot is how you're building up the signature base string.

Only the initial **&** should be left unencoded, however the rest of them in the signature base string should be encoded. It looks like the **&** after the encoded URL and encoded date query param are being left unencoded.

Edit:
The following two lines are leaving the &s out ouf encoding, but they need to be included in the uri encoding

```
encodeURIComponent(URL) + "&" +
encodeURIComponent('date=2019-02-01') + "&" +
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the lines with the issues I've mentioned

Comment: In your new snippet, it looks like the ordering of you parameters going into the signature base string have changed. Namely, oauth_token has moved to earlier in the list. The ordering of the parameters going into the signature base string is important. They need to be ordered in lexicographical byte ordering. In short that means params need to be ordered alphabetically, uppercase first and then lowercase. See my answer here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40335586/4878992

Comment: You've changed it around again and disregarded my original answer. The First & should not be encoded. Try this: var signatureBase = "GET&" + encodeURIComponent(URL + "&" + 'date=2019-02-01' + "&" + "oauth_consumer_key=" + CONSUMER_KEY +
            "&oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=" +
            oauth_timestamp + "&oauth_token=" + CONSUMER_KEY + "&oauth_version=1.0");